# How to include Composer within a GitHub repository

Tags: php, wordpress, git, github, composer-php

I am new to both Composer and Git/GitHub so please excuse me if this is a stupid question!

I have built a WordPress plugin which I have in a repository on GitHub and I will use the repository to distribute updates to the plugin using this plugin update checker library: https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker

The plugin has a number of Composer dependencies that I have installed. I've been researching and apparently you aren't supposed to include the composer vendors directory in your GitHub repository (see here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md) however my confusion is how can I distribute the plugin from GitHub using the update checker if the vendors directory is not included?

What is the correct way to achieve this? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks a lot in advance, Hayden

Comment: Generally speaking, most people would tell you not to track `vendor`. Instead, most people would recommend to create a build task that performs a `composer install` with some additional optimizations and attaches a zip to a dedicated release in GitHub, and it appears that that plugin supports that, too. This might be a little more involved than you wish however. Tracking `vendor` in GitHub for this specific scenario isn't the end of the world, and if your install-base is small and/or controlled, it might not be a bad idea.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you for your knowledge. Do you happen to have any resources or examples you can send me regarding the build task? I would like to learn more about that if possible. Also do you know why people would say not to track vendors? I'm struggling to understand why it's an issue. Thanks again!

Comment: @HaydenIngham You already seem to have `composer.json` in your repository. It also has `require` section. I think `vendor` directory will be created once user runs `composer install`. Are you confused about something more specific or just whether this is the right approach?

Comment: @HaydenIngham, unfortunately I don't at this time. All of my public plugins are currently hosted in the official WordPress repo and use SVN, and all of my other plugins are manually maintained for individual clients. But what you want to look into are "GitHub actions" which take a little bit to setup, but once you get it they go pretty easy.

Comment: @vish the users will not be able to run 'composer install'. They are end users who do not have that knowledge. My plugin will be installed via a zip file on their WordPress site. Also, I'm not sure if you are confused the GitHub link above is not my repository. That is a WordPress plugin update checker I will be including within my plugin. My repository does include a 'composer.json' file however if the vendors folder is not included then the dependencies won't be installed because the users of the plugin won't be able to do 'composer install'. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @HaydenIngham perhaps you need to give scenario example. Take a simple user who would want to use your plugin. What would they have on their machine? What would they need to use your plugin? Where are they going to place it? If your repository has readme.md, you can take relevant parts and paste it here?

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for your hlep

Comment: @vish okay, the user will be the owner of a swimming school with a WordPress website. They have no coding experience and wish to download my plugin from my website as a .zip file and install in on their WordPress website by uploading the .zip file to the add new plugin page. Once installed future updates will come via my GitHub repository and I need the composer dependencies to be included within the WordPress plugin both install and future updates without the user having to run any commands via the terminal (obviously). Surely some WordPress plugins out there use composer dependencies also?

Comment: @vish, I think the OP wants this to be used by the simplest of users. They download a plugin from a website as a zip file, possibly after paying for it, and then upload it to the plugin area. That's the extent of their technical knowledge. The OP wants to enable updates, but since the repo isn't with WordPress, they need to handle all of the logic on their own.

Comment: @ChrisHaas that's exactly right thank you for helping me explain that

Comment: Looks like we hit submit at almost the exact same time!

Comment: @HaydenIngham the reason why I asked was because there had to be a way let Wordpress manage that. Perhaps it is not possible but you can share that page with your users since those are only ways it seems. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/best-practice-with-plugin-development-and-composer/
https://wordpress.com/support/plugins/
https://community.platform.sh/t/how-to-install-custom-private-wordpress-plugins-and-themes-with-composer/622 More importantly, even I would be kinda apprehensive about doing something this technical as end user :) But then I want plugins, I have to get used it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I think we did!!

Comment: @vish thanks for those links. I’ll take a look. I’m a little confused with the whole composer working within a WordPress plugin to be honest. I’ll do some more research tomorrow and see if I can understand how the two can compliment each other and make it super easy for the end user. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @HaydenIngham I am more confused that you :) To think that I want to use third party plugin in wordpress, they\we seem to climb mountains; its surprising. All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of not committing the vendor folder makes sense in the case of a "composer-friendly" project, when running `composer install` is guaranteed by a build or release step and/or it is run manually during development.

I did not take a detailed look on the plugin-update-checker library you're using, but there are 2 cases:

1. It only knows to fetch code from a branch - if this is the case, then you will have to commit the vendor folder, there are no other options.
2. On the other hand, if it can handle getting the code from releases published on GitHub, then you can skip committing the vendor folder and only include it in your release builds. A pretty popular WordPress plugin does this, take a look on how they do it: https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo. You will see that vendor is not committed, but if you download a release, it is there in the archive.

Comment: Thanks Zoli, that’s really interesting. I’ll take a look at Yoast. The plugin checker works via releases as far as I know from looking at the readme on that repository. So maybe that means I could approach it like Yoast do.

Comment: Hi Zoli, seeing as releases are created from a branch in GitHub do you know how I would go about creating a release that includes the vendor folder if it's not there in the branch? I've been looking at Yoast and that setup seems to be the right thing to do but I can't get my head around how those releases are created including the vendor folder.

Comment: As far as I can think, you simply prepare the zip locally and add it as a binary when creating the release.

Answer (score -2):

add vendor folder to your .gitignore. someone can use (composer install) and (composer dump-autoload) for install your dependencies to project.

Comment: Hi Hirad, thanks but the people installing my plugin will be end users. They will not know how to use composer install. Surely there is a way to include composer in production projects otherwise what's the point of it!